# How to schedule and run a cron/launchctl job that will wake computer if asleep

Tags: backup, sleep-wake, launchd, rsync

I have a script that performs a backup of my PhD data using rsync. The rsync is performed between my laptop and a home server I have running. The broad idea here is that I normally use my server to process data since it has significantly more power than my laptop (VPN-ing in if I'm away from home as it's not outwardly accessible), but I want to keep a local copy of the data in case I am somewhere with an unstable/no connection, my home connection dies, etc so that I can keep working in those cases.

This script can take upwards of an hour to run if a lot of things have changed, so I'd like to automate this script to run in a way that wouldn't require me to remember to wake my laptop and possibly sit around waiting in the morning (Which isn't always an option) before leaving.

To that end, I want to set up my scheduled rsync job as a launchctl/cron job that will wake the computer somewhere around its scheduled run time to run. My reading so far has shown that these jobs can be set up to automatically run at the next opportunity if the computer was asleep/off at its scheduled run time, but that doesn't work for me since this backup can potentially take a while.

Is there a way to configure a launchctl/cron job to indicate that it should wake the computer to run? If it's relevant my plan is to only have this script run once a day, only if plugged in to power, and only if connected to my home network.

I'd also like to avoid continuous backup services (OwnCloud I think is the name?) because I don't want the backups to happen if I'm not connected to home wifi just because the data would quickly eat up my bandwidth cap if things are rapidly changing and it keeps trying to back up over the internet (even if through a VPN).